# How do write an SQL query that transforms phone numbers from columns into a single column?

Tags: sql, oracle, union, unpivot, lateral-join

How do I write an SQL query that transforms phone numbers from columns into a single column. Assume there are multiple personIDs and each personID has up to 3 phone types, Primary, Secondary and Tertiary. Currently, for each person, they are listed in three separate columns.

The desired outcome is that the phone numbers are all in one column, and another column has the phone types

Current Data

| Person_ID | Primary_Phone | Secondary_Phone | Tertiary_Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2221111111 | 5551111111 | 9991111111 |
| 2 | 2221111112 | 5551111112 | 9991111112 |
| 3 | 2221111113 | 5551111113 | 9991111113 |
| 4 | 2221111114 | 5551111114 | 9991111114 |

Desired Data

| Person_ID | Phone_Number | Phone_Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2221111111 | Primary |
| 1 | 5551111111 | Secondary |
| 1 | 9991111111 | Tertiary |
| 2 | 2221111112 | Primary |
| 2 | 5551111112 | Secondary |
| 2 | 9991111112 | Tertiary |
| 3 | 2221111113 | Primary |
| 3 | 5551111113 | Secondary |
| 3 | 9991111113 | Tertiary |
| 4 | 2221111114 | Primary |
| 4 | 5551111114 | Secondary |
| 4 | 9991111114 | Tertiary |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to want to do an `unpivot`

```
with p as (
  select 1 person_id, 
         '2221111111' primary_phone, 
         '5551111111' secondary_phone, 
         '9991111111' tertiary_phone
    from dual
  union all
  select 2, 
         '2221111112' primary_phone, 
         '5551111112' secondary_phone, 
         '9991111112' tertiary_phone
    from dual
)
select person_id,
       phone_number,
       phone_type
  from p
unpivot (
  phone_number
  for phone_type in (
     primary_phone as 'Primary',
     secondary_phone as 'Secondary',
     tertiary_phone as 'Tertiary'
  )
)
```

A [liveSQL link](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/k5t8142yayqjl906oxw7m6tba) showing the query running

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle starting version 12c, you can unpivot the columns to rows with `cross apply`:

```
select t.person_id, x.*
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select primary_phone as phone_number, 'Primary' as phone_type from dual
    union all select secondary_phone, 'Secondary' from dual
    union all select tertiary_phone, 'Tiertiary' from dual
) x
```

In earlier versions, you could use `union all`:

```
select person_id, primary_phone as phone_number, 'Primary' as phone_type from mytable
union all select person_id, secondary_phone, 'Secondary' from mytable
union all select person_id, tertiary_phone, 'Tiertiary' from mytable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Either option would certainly help